# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir "/tmp" must be a directory'

Tags: php, .htaccess, twitter-bootstrap, zend-framework, caching

I have problem regarding zend cache_dir.
I try to tranfer my site from one server to another, and it work.
But, when i try to access the site, it shows this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Cache_Exception' with message 'cache_dir "/tmp" must be a directory' in /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache.php:209
Stack trace:

- #0 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(178): Zend_Cache::throwException('cache_dir "/tmp...')
- #1 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php(129): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->setCacheDir('/tmp')
- #2 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache.php(153): Zend_Cache_Backend_File->__construct(Array)
- #3 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache.php(94): Zend_Cache::_makeBackend('File', Array, false, false)
- #4 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/application/Bootstrap.php(55): Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', Array, Array)
- #5 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(669): Bootstrap->_initCache()
- #6 /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(622): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-> in /home/aiesorgm/public_html/gcpi/library/Zend/Cache.php on line 209
```

---

I already try all solutions that i can get from stackoverflow, but it's still doesn't work.
I also have create tmp directory inside public folder and change the permission to 777.

**application/Bootstrap.php**

```
protected function _initCache() {
    $info = Zend_Registry::get('info');

    $backendOptions = array(
        'cache_dir' => sys_get_temp_dir(),
        'hashed_directory_level' => 1,
        'file_name_prefix' => 'style',
        'automatic_cleaning_factor' => 1
    );
    $frontendOptions = array(
        'lifetime' => $info['cache']['lifetime'],
        'automatic_serialization' => true,
        'caching' => ($info['cache']['enabled'] == '1') ? true : false,
    );
    $cache = Zend_Cache::factory('Page', 'File', $frontendOptions, $backendOptions);
    Zend_Registry::set('cache', $cache);
}
```

**/library/Zend/Cache/Backend/File.php**

```
    protected $_options = array(
    'cache_dir' => null,
    'file_locking' => true,
    'read_control' => true,
    'read_control_type' => 'crc32',
    'hashed_directory_level' => 0,
    'hashed_directory_perm' => 0700,
    'file_name_prefix' => 'zend_cache',
    'cache_file_perm' => 0600,
    'metadatas_array_max_size' => 100
);
```

***Folder Structure***

### application

- config
- controller
- form
- layouts
- models
- view

**docs**

**library**

### **public**

- css
- js
- images
- tmp
- .htaccess
- index.php

---

10Q for your time for reading this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`/tmp` is the full path, so ZF isn't trying to write to a folder called `tmp` in your public folder, it's trying to write to the system temp folder at the root of the file system.

I'd recommend setting a project-specific cache folder instead:

```
$backendOptions = array(
    'cache_dir' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/../data/cache',
    'hashed_directory_level' => 1,
    'file_name_prefix' => 'style',
    'automatic_cleaning_factor' => 1
);
```

then create a folder called `data` within your project, and a `cache` folder within that, and make it writeable.